# The same GroupName for few instances of a UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls, groupname

I have a number of own `UserControl`s on a page. Each has the same type and a radio button inside. How can I force only one `RadioButton` to be checked?

I did next:

```
class myControl : UserControl
{
  [Category("Settings")]
  public string GroupName
  {
     set
     {
       radio.GroupName = value;
     }
   }
}
```

but it doesn't helped.

Or only one way is to (un)check each radio button manually?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm,
You may want to use the `radiobuttonlist` control instead.  See: http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net/aspnetcontrols11.asp.

`radiobuttonlist` controls give you the grouping that you are after.

Comment: I cannot use RadioButtonList because besides RadioButtons my UserControls contains a lot of other controls, but I need common GroupName for all my UserControls on the page

Comment: Sorry I don't have the code to hand, but in the past when I've been in a situation like yours, you can just use normal html radiobutton <input> controls, but make them runat="server" so that you can access them from the codebehind.  Then you can group them as per normal, and they will only let one be selected at a time.


Or you can do some javascript to check clientside to make sure only one is checked.  I usually use JQuery for this sort of thing, it's pretty powerful.

Comment: Unfortunately doing runat="server" will mangle the name, which makes this approach unworkable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `input type="radio"` with this and give all the radio buttons the same name but different id. This way it will work without any problem. Try it yourself and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've gotten this to work is to use old school ASP interpolation:

```
<input type="radio" name="MyRadioButtons" value="<%=TheRightValue%>" />
```